# Short proof of $\frak p=t$

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, cardinal-characteristics

It is known for a while now that $\frak p=t$, as a result of Malliaris-Shelah. The original paper draws from model theoretic methods.

I've heard rumors that there was a proof which was purely set theoretic, and indeed much shorter than the original.

Does anyone know who wrote it, and whether or not it appears online/in print, and if so, is there an available link/reference?

Comment: For the set-theoretically ignorant among us: http://shelah.logic.at/files/998.pdf.

Comment: I've heard Juris Steprans has a manuscript with such a proof. Not so sure that it's "purely set theoretic" though, I've heard it's mostly a translation of sorts into the set-theoretic language (so someone without a lot of knowledge in model theory can understand it), but using the same underlying ideas.

Comment: Dear Asaf, I attached a paper by Steprans, which gives a proof of p=t by set theoretic methods.

Comment: David Fremlin recently uploaded a note on this result based on (what I think is) the note by Juris Steprans that is mentioned above: http://www.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/n14528.pdf

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One reference is given above by Inamdar that can be found here:

[$\frak p=t$, following Malliaris-Shelah and Steprans](https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/n14528.pdf) ([Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20180605111554/https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/n14528.pdf)).

Also there is another reference where not only it gives a proof of the $\frak p=t$ based on Steprans ideas, but it also gives in a very nice way some other results proved by Malliaris-Shelah:

[Ultraproducts of finite partial orders and some of their applications in model theory and set theory](http://www.logicatorino.altervista.org/matteo_viale/tesi-moranarocca.pdf) ([Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20180605111721/http://www.logicatorino.altervista.org/matteo_viale/tesi-moranarocca.pdf))

Answer (score 5):

While not short, [A Measure Theoretic Proof of $\mathfrak p=\mathfrak t$](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.14171) gives a proof that does not rely on model theoretic or proof theoretic techniques. Since the measure theory is basic, Kunen's text is sufficient background. (It in fact establishes a stronger result which implies the equality.)

To my knowledge, all of the other proofs are distillations of the original Malliaris--Shelah proof.