# Intuition for the infinite cardinals p and t (now that p = t)?

Tags: set-theory

I wonder if there are natural examples of sets whose cardinality is $\frak p$
and $\frak t$?
Examples that could provide intuition for non- set-theory experts?
I find the definitions in the Malliaris & Shelah paper that established
$\frak p=t$ difficult to grok, so to speak.
I am not asking to understand the proof, just to understand the cardinals themselves.

> Malliaris, Maryanthe, and Saharon Shelah. "Cofinality spectrum theorems in model theory, set theory, and general topology." *Journal of the American Mathematical Society* 29.1 (2016): 237-297. 
>   ([Journal link](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2016-29-01/S0894-0347-2015-00830-X/home.html); [Link to earlier arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.5424).)

<sup>Related MO question:
[Short proof of $\frak p=t$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/168125/6094).</sup>

Comment: Now that they are equal? Apparently they were always equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each element of **p** and each element of **t**  is a countable family of infinite sets of natural numbers.
Let's start by giving an example of such family.

A simple example of a countable family of infinite sets of natural numbers would be $$E = \bigotimes_{j\in \Bbb N}  \{k \in \Bbb N : \exists m | k = jm \}$$ so that two elements of $E$ would be $\{ 2,4,6,8\cdots\}$ and $\{ 3,6,9,12\cdots\}$.  We can say that a countable family of infinite sets of natural numbers is a subset of $[\Bbb N]^{\aleph_0}$. (We will see that this particular $E$ is not in **p**.)

Now let's define a relationship between sets $A$ and $B$ which I will call "is almost a subset of," written as $A \subseteq^* B$. 
In words, $A$ is almost a subset of $B$ iff only a finite set of elements of $A$ are not also in $B$.  That is, 
$$A \subseteq^* B \Leftrightarrow |\{ x:x\in A \wedge x \not\in B\}| < \infty $$ For example if $A$ is the set of primes and $B$ is the set of odd natural numbers, then $\{ x:x\in A \wedge x \not\in B\} = \{2\}$ and $A \subseteq^* B$.

Note that it is quite possible for $A \subseteq^* B$ and $B \subseteq^* A$.

---

Now let's define **p** and give an example of one element of **p**.

**p** is the set of all countable families of infinite sets of natural numbers such that family $f \in \mathbf{p}$ if and only if two conditions are met:

- Every non-empty finite subfamily of $f$ (every finite collection of sets, all of which are in $f$) has an infinite intersection.
- But there is no infinite set of integers $A$ such that $A$ is almost a subset of each element of $f$.  That is, $\left( \forall A \subseteq \Bbb N: B \in f \implies A \subseteq^* B \right) \implies |A| = \infty$.

You can see that these two conditions work against one another in some sense.  A simple example of a family of sets $f_1$ meeting the first condition is 
$\left\{ \{ n+0 :n \in \Bbb N\},\{ n+1 :n \in \Bbb N\}, \cdots \right\}$ since the intersection of any finite number of elements of $f_1$ consists of all numbers $\geq$ the highest starting point of any of that finite set of elements.

But that family $f_1$ fails the second condition, because if $A$ is the (infinite) set of even integers, then $A$ is almost a subset of each member of $f_1$.

An example of an element of **p** is the family of sets (indexed by $k\in \Bbb N$) of the form $\{ m^k : k\in \Bbb N\}$. The first condition is met since if $\ell$ is the least common multiple of all the indices in the finite sub-family 
then the set $\{ m^\ell : m\in \Bbb N\}$ is in every set in the finite subfamily. The second condition is met since there are an infinite number of integers that are cubes but not squares and vice-versa, so any infinite set $A$ of integers is either not almost a subset of the squares, or not almost a subset of the cubes, unless all but a finite number of elements of $A$ are sixth powers.  But then $A$ won't be almost a subset of the fifth powers, unless all but a finite number of elements of $A$ are $30$-th  powers; and so forth.

---

Now let's define **t** and give an example of one element of **t**.

**t** is the set of all countable families of infinite sets of natural numbers that can be well-ordered by the $\subseteq^*$ relation.  (Remember, well-ordering will mean that if family  $T$ is in **t** then every (non-equivalent under $A \subseteq^* B$) pair of elements of $T$ can be related by $\subseteq^*$ in one direction or the other, and every subset of $T$ has a least element in that ordering.)

A simple example of an element of **t** is 
the family $f_1$ described above.  This "tower" happens not to be in **p**.

The **p** = **t** question, then, is whether **p** can be mapped onto **t**, or **t** can be mapped onto **p**, or they are in $1:1$ correspondence.

---

In the paper by Malliaris and $(\mbox{Shelah})^2$ there is a minor wording error in definition 1.1 whch might be causing some confusion:  The first bullet should read

> $D$ has an **infinite** pseudo-intersection if there is an infinite $A\subseteq \Bbb N$ such that $\forall B\in D, A \subseteq^* B$.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask, what does "indexed by $k \in BbbN$" mean?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I guess it is meant to $\mathbb{N}$, and Mark accidentally used the command he is used to using in a personal setup.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I think he just forgot a backslash... \Bbb works with MathJax it seems and is equivalent to \mathbb. Fixed now.

Comment: The paper is by M. Malliaris and S. Shelah and S. Shelah; thus the $\mbox{(Shelah)}^2$.  On a move serious note, I neglected an important condition to be a tower: It also needs to have no infinite pseudo-intersection.  I think my example $f_1$ meets this condition but I'm not certain.

Comment: Not that it matters, but the AMS [journal link](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2016-29-01/S0894-0347-2015-00830-X/home.html) says the authors are M.M. and S.Shelah, punkt: no second S.Shelah.

Comment: Does this result $\frak{p}=\frak{t}$ imply that there is no cardinal in $]\aleph_0,2^{\aleph_0}[$ ?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but in the second bullet point in the definition of **b**, shouldn't the part after the implication arrow be $|A| < \infty$, rather than $|A| = \infty$? After all, just before you say that there is NO infinite set being almost contained in all elements of $f$.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of simple examples; they don't have cardinality $\mathfrak p$ or $\mathfrak t$ but depending on your knowledge they may or may not help.

They are families of sets of natural numbers that I'll call $\mathcal F$, $\mathcal L$, $\mathcal M$, and $\mathcal D$.

Let $\mathcal F=\{X\subseteq\mathbb N: X\text{ is co-finite}\}$ and $\mathcal L=\{[n,\infty)\cap\mathbb N: n\in\mathbb N\}$.

In terms of the definitions on page 2 of

> M. Malliaris, S. Shelah, *Cofinality spectrum theorems in model theory, set theory and general topology*, arXiv:[1208.5424](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.5424) (or [direct pdf link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.5424))

$\mathcal L$ is not a tower, because even though it is well-ordered by $\supseteq^*$, it has $\mathbb N$ itself as a pseudo-intersection (the elements of $\mathcal L$ are too big, so to speak).

Anyway, $\mathcal L$ is countable, so it's plausible that a tower would have to be uncountable, and indeed that's the cardinality $\mathfrak t$.

$\mathcal F$ is a bit bigger than $\mathcal L$, is not well-ordered by $\supseteq^*$, but still has the s.f.i.p. since the intersection of finitely many co-finite sets is still co-finite (since the union of finitely many finite sets is finite).

Like $\mathcal L$, the family $\mathcal F$ is countable and unfortunately has $\mathbb N$ as pseudo-intersection. So it's again plausible that the corresponding cardinal $\mathfrak p$ is uncountable.

So let's consider $\mathcal M$, the family of sets whose limiting (Banach) density is 1. It has the s.f.i.p. and no pseudo-intersection. Great! However, $\mathcal M$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Now consider $\mathcal D=\{\{k: k\text{ is divisible by }2^m\}: m\in\mathbb N\}$. This is also countable, well-ordered by $\supseteq$, but again unfortunately has an infinite pseudo-intersection, namely $\{1,2,4,8,16,\dots\}$.

$\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{Family }\quad & \text{Well-ordered?}\quad&\text{S.f.i.p.? }\quad & \text{pseudo-$\cap$? }&\text{Cardinality}\\
\mathcal F & \text{no}& \text{yes} &\text{yes}& \aleph_0\\
\mathcal L & \text{yes}& \text{yes} &\text{yes}& \aleph_0\\
\mathcal M & \text{no}& \text{yes} &\text{no}& 2^{\aleph_0}\\
\mathcal D & \text{yes}& \text{yes} &\text{yes}& \aleph_0\\
\end{eqnarray*}$