# Short proof of $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{t}$ by Juris Steprans

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

I have just read this question [Short proof of $\frak p=t$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168125/short-proof-of-frak-p-t).
The link present in the answer about the proof given by Steprans doesn't work anymore.
Since I don't have enough reputation neither to talk in the chat nor to comment directly there to ask to upload the link, I made this question.

Can you provide me the updated link to the proof by Steprans of $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{t}$?

Comment: I have updated both links in the answer to the earlier question.  To make things tidy, I will vote to close this question as a duplicate of the earlier one.

Comment: Thank you very much for both answer and for updating the previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Fremlin's [webpage](https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/), in the section "[Miscellaneous research notes](https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/preprints.htm)".

Comment: 12 pages is short?

Comment: well, I guess it is "short" if compared with the size of the previous proofs :-)

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, it has been saved in the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/).

The following link will work: http://web.archive.org/web/20170706054653/http://www.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/n14528.pdf